className prop is not passed down to custom component in React Native
I have a custom component in which I want to pass className as props. But the prop is not available in the child component. What am I doing wrong?
// Parent component
<MyComponent className="flex-1" otherName="flex-2" />

// Child component
function MyComponent({className, otherName}: {className: string, otherName: string}) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{className}</Text>
      <Text>{otherName}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

Output shows only "flex-2" and not "flex-1"..
